# The documentation header is composed of invalid xml

Tags: stylecop

I am trying to implement StyleCop.MSBuild in project. And I am stuck at this error.

**Error SA1603 : CSharp.Documentation : The documentation header is composed of invalid Xml: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character.**

This is my class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Abstract class of type T
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the value for which database operations will be performed</typeparam> 
public abstract class DataAccessBase<T> : IDataAccessBase<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataAccessBase<T>" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sqlDataBaseSettings">Instance of SQL database settings</param>
        public DataAccessBase(ISqlDatabaseSettings sqlDataBaseSettings)
        {    
            this.SqlDataBaseSettings = sqlDataBaseSettings;
        }
 }
```

I get the error at the summary of constructor.
If I don't put `<T>` I still get the error.

**Error SA1642 : CSharp.Documentation : The documentation text within the constructor's summary tag must begin with the text: Initializes a new instance of the  class**